# C++11 lambda and template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

I would like to know what is the correct type definition for the lambda presented below, so that the following code will compile using a conformant c++11 compiler:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

template<class Func>
class foo
{
public:
   foo(Func func)
   : fum(func){}
   Func fum;
};

int main()
{
   foo<???> fi([](int i) -> bool { printf("%d",i); return true; });
   fi.fum(2);
   return 0;
}
```

I guess another way it could be done is like so:

```
template<typename Func>
foo<Func> make_foo(Func f)
{
   return foo<Func>(f);
}

int main()
{
   auto fi = make([](int i) -> bool { printf("%d",i); return true; });
   fi.fum(2);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's `auto` + `decltype`:

```
auto l = [](int i) -> bool { printf("%d",i); return true; };
foo<decltype(l)> fi(l);
fi.fum();
```

Every single lambda has a different, unique, unnamed type. You, as a coder, just *can not* name it.

However, in your case, since the lambda doesn't capture anything (empty `[]`), it is implicitly convertible to a pointer-to-function, so this would do:

```
foo<bool(*)(int)> fi([](int i) -> bool { printf("%d",i); return true; });
fi.fum();
```

Comment: Should be `foo<decltype(l)>` instead of `foo(decltype(l))`

Comment: @Kerrek: Damn bracket confusion in C++. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's `std::function<bool(int)>`. Or possibly just `bool(*)(int)` if you prefer, since the lambda doesn't capture.

(The raw function pointer might be a bit more efficient, since `std::function` does (at least in some cases) require dynamic allocation for some type erasure magic.)

Comment: btw what would it look like if i were to capture everything by reference '[&]' ?

Comment: I'd have upboated for the `decltype` argument presented by Xeo.

Comment: @JaredKrumsie: In that case you must use `function`: The type of the closure object is not nameable by you, and all you know that it is *convertible* to the corresponding `std::function` type. A capturing lambda is a complex object, not just a free function, so it cannot possibly be expressible as a function pointer in any direct fashion.

Comment: @DeadMG: It should be said that Xeo's two-line approach has the advantage that for a capturing lambda you do not incur the cost of constructing the `std::function` object, which is a Good Thing. My answer was trying to take the question literal.