# lambda as template parameter with access to 'this' pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I have to create objects of three-four classes, all inherited from one base class, but some of the objects need to have different behavior - like complete change of one function; I can do this through more inheritance and polymorphism, but it doesn't seem like a good idea.
My first solution was to use specialized templates(for every nonstandard case), but then I have though about lambdas as template parameter(like here: [Can we use a lambda-expression as the default value for a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741652/parameterized-lambda-expression-as-a-default-function-argument) ) and use them instead class method(like here: [C++11 lambda and template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528570/c11-lambda-and-template-specialization) ) - for me it's much better solution, because I only have to pass lambda for every weird situation:

```cpp
auto default_lambda = [&]() -> int {return this->Sth;};
template<typename functor = decltype(default_lambda)>
class SomeClass{
...
```

Problem is with this pointer - method which I want to change need access to non-static methods and lambda is defined outside of non-static method. Moreover, I can't pass reference to class to lambda, because it's a template class(or maybe I'm wrong?).
Of course, I can use specialized template or just function pointers, but I really like solution with lambdas and I consider it much more fine than my other ideas.
Is there any way to "avoid" this problem? Or maybe my idea was bad all along?

Comment: Please post the actual problem you're trying to solve (minimal, complete, representative example).  Perhaps this can be solved with a member-pointer...

Comment: "I can do this through more inheritance and polymorphism, but it doesn't seem like a good idea." Why not? That's what polymorphism is *for*.

Comment: I second @NicolBolas here. People tend unfortunately to frown upon polymorphism, as if it was out of fashion. It seems to me that you can solve your problem using either 1) one virtual function (that's what they are for !) 2) `std::function`, since you may want to bind the function at construction time (local classes could help should you choose 1))

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three obvious problems with your approach:

1. The class `SomeClass` won't get access to private members, i.e. use of `this` is out of question.
2. You attempt to bind `this` from the context but there is no context i.e. nothing bind to. You will have to pass the object to dealt with a function parameter.
3. You only specified a type of the function object but no instance, i.e. you won't be able to use it later.

That said, it seems you could just use the type of a custom function object type rather than some lambda function (sure, this is absolutely unsexy but in return it actually works):

```
struct default_lambda {
    template <typename T>
    int operator()(T const& o) const { return o.x(); }
};
template <typename F = default_lambda>
class SomeClass {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need complete change of one function, you have two choices:

- One virtual function, using perhaps local classes + type erasure if you have many such objects and you don't want to create many namespace scope types:
- `std::function`, which can be rebound later if you wish.

Example code for the first solution (you can even make this a template):

```
std::unique_ptr<my_base2> get_an_object()
{
    class impl : public my_base2
    {
        void my_virtual_function() { blah blah; }
    };

    return std::unique_ptr<my_base2>(new impl);
}
```

Both are generally superior to templates in this situation (but without context it is hard to tell).